# how can i stop a lua function block/call mid execution

Tags: lua

is there a way to stop a lua pcall to a lua function block from mid execution? Im using multiple threads and would be good to cancel a function mid-flight.

Comment: Lua itself doesn't support multi-threading. Explain how you are using multi threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to call `error('my message')` as this will abort the execution and will return `nil, 'my message'` as the result of `pcall()`. If you want to abort a running coroutine (or a "main" chunk) from "outside", the only way to do it I know about without modifying Lua VM is to attach a debug hook to coroutine or the main chunk and call `error()` from that debug hook:

```
print(1)
local count = 0
debug.sethook(function(event, line)
  if count > 1 then error('done', 2) end
  count = count + 1
end, "l")
print(2)
print(3)
print("not getting here")
```

You should see something like this:

```
1
2
3
script.lua:4: done
```

In the case of `pcall`, you will see the parameter of the `error()` call to be passed as the error message by `pcall`.

The conditions to check can get quite elaborate; for example, you can check for the hook to be called from a particular function with a certain number of commands executed before aborting.